# How do I view the achievements for a particular ship while in game?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

Sometimes I forget what the exact achievements are to unlock different ship layouts while playing, but I can't seem to figure out how to view them again without quitting the current game.

How can I view them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best bet will probably be to tab out and view [this web page](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Ship_Achievements). I know this isn't in game, but it will allow you to view them without quitting the current game.

Comment: that works fine, as long as its accessible somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Press [Esc] and view the [ships achievements](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Ship_Achievements).
See this [answer..](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/237446/124887)