# How can I see achievements while playing?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

Is there a way to see the game achievements after a new game started?

[image]

Comment: You should edit your question because I can't see what achievements you mean here. Is it Steam-Achievements or ingame or ios side or what?

Comment: Added a picture of the wanted 'achievements' for more clarification (learned my lesson well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press [**ESC**] --> [**Main Menu**] (Won't stop the current game state) --> [**STATS**] --> [*Achievements tab*].

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just push Escape while in a game and the menu will appear along with some other information including the achievements for the current ship class and type.

You cannot see achievements for other ships while in a game you will need to go back to the hanger.

[image: Image of FTL menu which shows the current ship achievements in the middle right]

Comment: If an answer if no longer valid, you should delete it, not just post a note that it's no longer valid.

Comment: Frank is right, this answers about 'ship achievement', while asked about achievement.
Definition of 'ship achievement' and 'achievements' can be found in the wiki: 
http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Ship_Achievements
http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements